# excel function to find last number in column

Tags: excel, function

I record the value of my stocks each day in columns and it is a long spreadsheet.  In the top cell of each column, I want to use a function that will display the last entry in the column automatically.  I've tried the Index function and the Index function combined with the Counta function with no success.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/last_value.php) is one approach; and [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/return-the-last-item-in-an-excel-column/732) is another.

Comment: @chuff you should summarise the answer from that first link into an answer here- it is the best answer to this question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using `LOOKUP`, assuming at most 1000 rows of data (adjust as required) use this formula in A1 to get the last number in A2:A1000

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,A2:A1000)`

You can have blanks or any other data in the range (even errors) and it will still return the last number

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank so much!!  BTW, what does the 9.99E+307 do?  I have never used this before.

Comment: No problem - 9.99E+307 is a shortened version of the largest number you can type in a cell in Excel - technically it's 9.99999999999999E+307 which is just short of a 1 with 308 zeroes. When you use that "Bignum" as the lookup value excel won't find a number that large.....and consequently returns the **last** value in the range - if it works for you can you accept my answer?

Comment: Combination of MATCH/INDEX can be used to achieve the same result, with 9.99E+307 as the match lookup value. It may be worth mentioning that the result with either method is *literally* the last number, i.e., any blank, text or error values that occur after the last numeric value will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks again.  This is the first time I've used stackoverflow, so I think I have now "accepted" your answer but feel free to let me know if I have not done that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for Column A, resp. Cell A1:

```
=OFFSET(A$2;ROWS(A$2:A$101)-COUNTBLANK(A$2:A$101)-1;0)
```

This example is for a maximum of 100 rows of data (2 - 101). You may replace `101` by any higher number according to the size of your sheet.

Please note that there may be **no** blank cells in the middle of the list.

Comment: I tried this using my cell numbers, but it didn't like the very first A$2 as the "reference".  What does "reference" in this function mean?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You probably need to use , in place of the ; values that Jens used - separators are region-specific.....

Answer (score 0):

The answer Jens Fischer provided worked excellently and also translated well to google sheets whereas other solutions have not. I made one small change; by using A$1 as the reference I didn't need the -1 at the end of the formula.