# Select cell above last cell of column

Tags: excel

I want to automatically select a cell 12 rows higher than the last cell of data in a column. I used the tips in this thread ([excel function to find last number in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892492/excel-function-to-find-last-number-in-column)) to automatically select the last cell of data using Lookup(9.99E+307,A1:A1000), but I am having trouble selecting the cell 12 rows above that. Would ADDRESS work for this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

```
=INDEX(A1:A1000, MATCH(9^99, A1:A1000)-12)
```

`MATCH` works a little like `LOOKUP`, but instead of returning a value, it returns the row number where there was the last number. `INDEX` picks this row number up and returns the value in that particular row, minus 12.